# Por que quando tento dividir o valor da 0?

Tags: java

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lista3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Qual o valor do seu salario ?");
        int salariodousuario = entrada.nextInt();

        int salariominimo = 1100;

        int quantidadeDesalariosminimos = salariominimo/salariodousuario;

        System.out.println("Você ganha um total de " + quantidadeDesalariosminimos + " salarios minimos.");


    }
}
```

Comment: aaaaaaa, muito obrigado, clareou bastante minha mente agora.

Answer (score 2):

**isso pode aconteccer caso tu recebas um floar ou double como resultado.
tipo:**

> ## 1 / 2 = 0.5

#### como tu armazenas o resultado numa variavel do tipo inteiro então ela(a variavel) vai pegar simplesmente a parte inteira.

#### `podes tentar 3 / 2 = 1.5 e terás 1 como resultado`

Answer (score 0):

Para ter a media de salarios minimos em cima do salario do usuario voce tem que dividir o salario do usuario pelo salario minimo. E tambem voce esta usando int, ele arredonda o valor para baixo. Ex:  10/6 = 1. Para um resultado exato usa double ao inves de int.